# OpenGL ES 1.1 is it possible to have both - vertexColors AND lighting?

Tags: opengl-es, colors, lighting, vertex

If I have a mesh that uses vertexColors and then enable GL_LIGHTING, then the vertexColors will be ignored and replaced by the calculated lighting.

Is there a way in OpenGL ES 1.1 to have both at the same time - vertex colors & dynamic lighting?

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
glEnable(GL_COLOR_MATERIAL);
```

to have the material parameters track the current color. On desktop OpenGL implementations there is also [glColorMaterial](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glColorMaterial.xml) to configure if the color is to be applied as the ambient of diffuse value, in OpenGL-ES I think it alway applies to both.

Comment: but what if I want to visualize some mesh property per vertex?

Comment: @Mat, I'm not sure I understood your comment, but with `GL_COLOR_MATERIAL` the ambient and diffuse material parameters will be set according to the vertex colors and get used in the lighing calculations..