# Vertex coloring not working with dynamically created meshes when using lighting

Tags: java, 3d, desktop-application, libgdx

I have created a Mesh object containing position, normal, and color information using the following code:

```
final Vector3[] vertexVectors = this.getVertexVectors();
final short[] indices = this.getIndices();
final Vector3[] vertexNormals = this.getNormals(vertexVectors, indices);
final float[] vertices = new float[vertexVectors.length * 7];

for (int index = 0; index < vertexVectors.length; index++)
{
    vertices[(index * 7) + 0] = vertexVectors[index].x;
    vertices[(index * 7) + 1] = vertexVectors[index].y;
    vertices[(index * 7) + 2] = vertexVectors[index].z;

    vertices[(index * 7) + 3] = vertexNormals[index].x;
    vertices[(index * 7) + 4] = vertexNormals[index].y;
    vertices[(index * 7) + 5] = vertexNormals[index].z;

    vertices[(index * 7) + 6] = Color.toFloatBits(0, 255, 0, 255);
}

final Mesh mesh = new Mesh(true, vertices.length / 3, indices.length, new VertexAttribute(Usage.Position, 3, "a_position"), new VertexAttribute(Usage.Normal, 3, "a_normal"), new VertexAttribute(Usage.ColorPacked, 4, "a_color"));
mesh.setVertices(vertices);
mesh.setIndices(indices);
return mesh;
```

I then create a Model object and a ModelInstance object from the mesh with this code:

```
private Model model;
private ModelInstance instance;

final ModelBuilder modelBuilder = new ModelBuilder();
modelBuilder.begin();
modelBuilder.part("0", this.getCustomMesh(), GL10.GL_TRIANGLES, new Material());
this.model = modelBuilder.end();
this.instance = new ModelInstance(this.model);
```

I render the ModelInstance using this code:

```
Gdx.gl.glViewport(0, 0, Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), Gdx.graphics.getHeight());
Gdx.gl.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL10.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

this.modelBatch.begin(this.cam);
this.modelBatch.render(this.instance, this.lights);
this.modelBatch.end();
```

My problem is that the model has no color.  The model should be green per the vertex colors but as long as I use lighting, the model appears white.  If i remove the lighting, the model appears green as expected (but without the pretty shading).  I have tried adding `Gdx.gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_COLOR_MATERIAL);` to my constructor per [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4841715/opengl-es-1-1-is-it-possible-to-have-both-vertexcolors-and-lighting), but this only makes the model appear brighter but still white.  What other settings are needed for my model to render the vertex colors with lighting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems adding `ColorAttribute.createDiffuse` to the model's material fixes the issue.  This means changing this line:

```
modelBuilder.part("0", this.getCustomMesh(), GL10.GL_TRIANGLES, new Material());
```

with this:

```
modelBuilder.part("0", this.getCustomMesh(), GL10.GL_TRIANGLES, new Material(ColorAttribute.createDiffuse(0, 0, 0, 0)));
```

I do not fully understand why and as an added curiosity, the values passed to the createDiffuse method seem to have no noticeable affect on the model.